# UDP- server and client ip for for far connection

Tags: python, sockets, blender

I built a network game with blender game engine with udp socket, I have server.blend and client.blend. In my home, the game works great and the connection so on.. but when I sent the client.blend to a friend he couldn't connect to my server..

This is my server constructor:

```
class Server:

def __init__(self, host="", port= 9017):

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.socket.setblocking(False)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.socket.bind((host, port))
```

this is my client's constructor:

```
class Client:

def __init__(self, server_ip="192.168.1.12", server_port= 9017):

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.socket.setblocking(False)

    self.serv_addr = (server_ip, server_port)
```

I believe it's not working on my friend's computer because of the ip addresses.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: The Internet is more complicated than that. You are likely behind a firewall doing address translation (NAT), which is blocking incoming UDP packets. You're friend won't be able to reach your internal IP address directly. To do this you'd have to make a special firewall rule.

Comment: I understand... lets say i want to do that special firewall rule.. is it complicated? do you know how to do this?

Comment: That depends on what kind you have. If using Linux you can [find some tuturials online](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/iptables-add-rule/). But you probably don't so you'll have to refer to the manual of your model. Unfortunately, many commercial models don't let you do this kind of thing.

Comment: I guess it makes sense... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard-coded IP you're using is an RFC 1918 private IP address, which is not routable over the internet. If your friend was connected to the same local area network as you he would likely be able to connect to your server. Fundamentally, this boils down to a network issue.

Possible solutions could be to define a host name in your application and use a DynDNS provider to register that host name with your router's public IP. Then set up port forwarding on your home router to allow connections from the Internet into your server on the udp ports you need. There's a thousand other ways to go about something like this but really this falls into the realm of networking than programming.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that what that shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzVpkat16-Y may work?